# Put foreach loop result as an key php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to loop a foreach loop in a array, and the loop result should be as the keys of the new array, like this,

```
$names = array('joe', 'piter', 'jack');
$dates = array('06/22/1987', '05/25/1988', '08/26/1990');
$arr = array();
foreach($names as $v){
     $arr[] = $v;
}
$arr2 = array($arr => $dates);
print_r($arr2);
```

How do I do that?

Thnaks guys.

Comment: What would be the desired output in this case?

Comment: I think you might be looking for [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).  It takes 2 arrays and creates a new array with the keys being from one array and the values from the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for a foreach loop to achieve that. Just use [array_combine](http://php.net/array-combine):

```
$names = array('joe', 'piter', 'jack');
$dates = array('06/22/1987', '05/25/1988', '08/26/1990');
$arr2 = array_combine($names, $dates);
```

`print_r($arr2)` Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [joe] => 06/22/1987
    [piter] => 05/25/1988
    [jack] => 08/26/1990
)
```

In this situation you don't need to do this, but if you want to know how to use `$v` as a key for `$arr2` in your loop you can just do the assignment in your loop:

```
$arr2[$v] = ...;
```

Comment: But if I want that each key should be an array, how do I do that?

Comment: @thegrede You can't use `arrays` for keys. The key must be a string or integer. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.  If you really want you can convert an array to a string with `serialize` and then use it as a key, but I highly recommend against that.

Comment: @ascii-lime There is a way of using objects as array key by extending the ArrayObject and overriding the OffsetSet method, by implementing ArratAccess and implementing your own OffsetSet method and I also remember it being possible with the SplObserver/SplSubject interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Well, saw @ascii-lime's answer (which is much better) after I typed this up, but just as an alternative I guess...

```
$names = array('joe', 'piter', 'jack');
$dates = array('06/22/1987', '05/25/1988', '08/26/1990');
$arr = array();
$i=0;
foreach($names as $v){
    $arr[$v] = $dates[$i];
    ++$i;
}
print_r($arr);
```